# Inline forms >> Horizontal forms for mobile resolutions

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to have two form elements inline for desktop resolutions, but on phone resolutions, it really screws up the look. Is there an easy way to take the below code and break it out of inline to stack them if a phone resolution is detected?

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputAmount">Amount (in dollars)</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Amount">
      <div class="input-group-addon">.00</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Transfer cash</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do that using two columns on extra small devices.
I wrapped the form inside `container` div.
I added single row with two columns of size 6 for extra small devices.
And i added my custom class `btn-sm-block` to the button in order to make it full width on small devices.

```css
@media all and (max-width:768px) {
    .btn-sm-block {
        width: 100%;
        display:block;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputAmount">Amount (in dollars)</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Amount">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">.00</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm-block">Transfer cash</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```